# How can I run a for loop within a case in a select statement (Oracle database)

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, case

For this to make some sense, let's think that I am reviewing all my items in a master list. One of my checks is to see if a particular item is an ingredient in cake recipes. I want to perform some additional checks on ingredient based on conditions on the cakes. Not all ingredients in the master are used in cake recipes.

Inside a CASE within a SELECT statement, I'm trying to iterate through all the unique cakes an ingredient can be part of.  If the ingredient is in a recipe, then I do a FOR LOOP for all the cakes. Right now my code works well without the FOR LOOP, but, once I add it, it gives me the following error:

**ORA-00936: missing expression**

This is my code (simplified, focusing on issue):

```
select     (CASE... END) as Case1,
           (CASE... END) as Case2,
           ...
           (CASE
                WHEN    ((select    count(*)
                        from        BOM
                        where       TRIM(MMCU)='MyPlant' and
                                    ITM=IB.ITM AND
                                    TBM IN ('M', 'ALT', 'AL2', 'AL3') AND
                                    (EFFF<=SYSDATE AND
                                    EFFT>=SYSDATE))>=1) THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN IB.STKT='P' THEN
                            FOR parentItem IN   (select     distinct KIT
                                                from        BOM
                                               where       TRIM(MMCU)='MyPlant' AND
                                                            ITM=IB.ITM AND
                                                            TBM IN ('M', 'ALT', 'AL2', 'AL3') AND
                                                            (EFFF<=SYSDATE AND
                                                            EFFT>=SYSDATE)
                                                order by    KIT)
                            LOOP
                                dbms_output.put_line(parentItem)
                            END LOOP
                            CASE
                                WHEN IB.SAFE>0 THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
                        ELSE 1
                    END
                ELSE 1
            END) as CaseN,
            (CASE... END) as CaseX
from        MasterList IB
...
```

The query fails on the line where the FOR LOOP starts. What is missing for the loop to work?

Comment: You cannot have procedural code (PL/SQL) in SQL statements. Additionally a loop seems inefficient here anyway and the whole question rather seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you want to check if something exists, i.e. a reference to an ingredient in a cake recipe, use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery. Unfortunately I don't understand how the query you posted matches the description, so I cannot give you any more details. The schema's DDL along with DML for sample data and the desired result with that sample data might fix this.

Comment: Oracle SQL has no `loop` clause, or any way to call procedures. Perhaps sample data and results would help clarify the kind of query you need.

Comment: @stickybit: Thanks for that. Your comment made me think of an alternative approach and I'll follow that one.